# ansible, spaces in command line variables

Tags: ansible

I am about to bump up the changelog of a lot of locally developed debian packages. I am using 'Ansible' to call 'dch' from the devscripts package. I am using Ansible because I already have the subversion paths to the packages listed in an Ansible variable. I would like to be able to enter the actual changelog message as a command line variable, but it seems that ansible cannot parse spaces in variables entered on the command line.

I have tried

```
ansible-playbook tag_changelog_on_packages.yml -e changelog_message="testing testing"
ansible-playbook tag_changelog_on_packages.yml -e changelog_message='testing testing'
ansible-playbook tag_changelog_on_packages.yml -e changelog_message=testing\ testing
ansible-playbook tag_changelog_on_packages.yml -e changelog_message="testing\ testing"
```

In all cases I only get the first "testing" . The last try makes ansible crash with `ValueError: No escaped character` probably because the whitespace is stripped.

Am I missing anything ?

Cheers

Answer (score 34, accepted):

That is because it is processed by shell first which eats the quotes and backslashes you used.

You can enclose the whole argument into single quotes which tells shell not to touch what is inside. Then the value of the variable can be enclosed into double quotes, which will remain there for ansible.

`ansible-playbook tag_changelog_on_packages.yml -e 'changelog_message="testing testing"'`

EDIT: As Ken Pronovici pointed out in the comment, reversing the quotation marks makes more sense as it enables the use of shell vars:

`-e "name='${NAME}'"`

Comment: For others coming here looking for a way to make this work with shell variables that contain spaces, this basic principle still works, but you'll have to reverse the double and single quotes, like `-e "name='${NAME}'"`

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH!! I've spent a couple of hours on this and could not get it to work.

Comment: I dumped 1,5h for that BS just now... Thanks a hell of a lot!

Comment: I had a similar issue, and this solved it, thank you.
I was providing in a var a script containing several whitespace-separated parameters, as it was passed to a script that expected that, but it was just passing the first part of that literal.
This was a testing example the case:
`ansible-playbook  ....  --extra-var dnslist="8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4" `
It just passed 8.8.8.8.
Adding the quotes, it worked. For example:
`ansible-playbook  ....  --extra-var 'dnslist="8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4"' `

Comment: mitroo, suggest updating your answer with the comment from @KenPronovici - it makes for a more general solution. Thanks!